# MySQL - One to Many Join - Return results for only 1 row from "One" table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry....should have said, this is MySQL.

Ok....first and foremost, I don't know if I can actually do what I am looking to do.  I have some experience with SQL, but not a ton.  Hopefully, someone can help.

I have two tables, one has orders and one has shipments.  I can do a join between them and get a proper result.....

Orders Table

```
Order_ID |  Revenue  |
1001     |  125.00   |
1002     |  215.31   |
1003     |  654.43   |
```

Shipments Table

```
Order_ID | Shipment_ID |  Item Count  |
1001     |    99001    |      25      |
1001     |    99002    |       5      |
1002     |    99003    |      65      |
1003     |    99004    |     123      | 
1003     |    99005    |      20      |
```

With a straight join on Order_ID, I get back the expected result:

```
Order_ID | Revenue  | Shipment_ID |  Item Count  |
1001     |  125.00  |   99001     |      25      |
1001     |  125.00  |   99002     |       5      |
1002     |  215.31  |   99003     |      65      |
1003     |  654.43  |   99004     |     123      | 
1003     |  654.43  |   99005     |      20      |
```

I am trying to reconcile revenue and cost in the same output, if possible.  I know from a separate table what the cost of each of my shipments was, so that math is simple.  However, my revenue is off this way because I have duplication in the revenue column, due to orders going in multiple shipments.

I would like to get something like the following:

```
Order_ID | Revenue  | Shipment_ID |  Item Count  |
1001     |  125.00  |   99001     |      25      |
1001     |  NULL    |   99002     |       5      |
1002     |  215.31  |   99003     |      65      |
1003     |  654.43  |   99004     |     123      | 
1003     |  NULL    |   99005     |      20      |
```

The values for the duplicate revenue numbers could be null, blank, 0, anything other than a value that will calculate.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Matthew

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, MySQL, SQL Server, ...?

Comment: Where is your cost column?  Unless you need detailed shipment output, you could likely create an output with one row per order, with the shipment costs summed.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the following query:

```
SELECT s1.Order_ID, s1.Shipment_ID, s1.Item_Count, 
       IF(s1.Shipment_ID = s2.minS_ID, o.Revenue, 0) AS Revenue
FROM Shipments AS s1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Order_ID, MIN(Shipment_ID) AS minS_ID
   FROM Shipments
   GROUP BY Order_ID
) AS s2 ON s1.Order_ID = s2.Order_ID
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON s1.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
```

The idea is to perform an additional join with a derived table that contains the minimum `Shipment_ID` per `Order_ID`. If the `Shipment_ID` value of the current row is equal to this value then return `Revenue`, else return 0.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c76/2)

In SQL Server you can use window version of `MIN` to make the comparison:

```
SELECT s.Order_ID, Shipment_ID, Item_Count,
       CASE 
          WHEN MIN(Shipment_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Order_ID) = Shipment_ID THEN Revenue
          ELSE 0
       END AS Revenue            
FROM Shipments AS s
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON s.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
```